# Is it possible to have what I draw in my custom UIButton's drawRect be "darkened" when the user interacts with the UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, drawrect

I add an shape to my custom `UIButton` in its `drawRect` method, but when I tap on the button the shape is not dimmed like the rest of the `UIButton` is. Is it possible to make it so it does do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you can do it with a shape you draw directly in the button, but if you add your shape as the background image of the button, it will be dimmed on touch. In the following example, I add an oval to a button that was sized to 80 x 40 in IB,

```
-(void)drawShapeInButton {
    UIBezierPath *oval = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0,0, 80, 40)];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(oval.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    [oval fill];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [self.button setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```